# How to access folder from server path

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, fileserver

I tried to access folder from my server path in my project but not working.I do not know where I did mistake or missing script.

```
var http = require('http');
//Actual path is http://proxy.ipt.org/power/confolder
var options = {
  host: 'http://proxy.ipt.org',
  port: 8081,
  path: '/power/confolder'
};

http.get(options, function(resp){
  resp.on('data', function(chunk){

          console.log(chunk);
          //How to read files and How to display what are the folders are there inside confolder

  });
}).on("error", function(e){
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Getting Error:  got error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://proxy.ipt.org/power/confolder

How to read confolder? If anyone know help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Your server must be configured to display folder content, and right now it isn't.

take a look at this for example:
https://www.keycdn.com/support/nginx-directory-index

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to remove 'http://' from options.host, so your options variable would be:

```
var options = {
  host: 'proxy.ipt.org',
  port: 8081,
  path: '/power/confolder'
};
```

Of course if http://proxy.ipt.org:8081/power/confolder does not reply to get request or the host is not reachable/does not exist you will get an error again. To read `confolder` you would need the server to return the content in some way but that's another topic that goes beyond how to request the content which is what you are trying here.

Here is a working example with a server that works and returns content when receiving a get request:

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
  host: 'nodejs.org',
  port: 80,
  path: '/dist/index.json',
};
http.get(options, function(resp){
  resp.on('data', function(chunk){
    console.log(chunk);
  });
}).on("error", function(e){
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Comment: If i use like this http://proxy.ipt.org:8081/power/confolder I am getting error Got error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.131.42.198:8081